# getting null pointer exception in android while trying to get values from radio button

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, radio-button

i have a layout register and i want to check if the user has entered all fields then move to next activity. I have checked that register_layout contains all the view that i want to access.

code for activity register.java

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button register_user;
private EditText first_name_et,last_name_et,email_id_et,mobile_no_et,password_et,address_et;  private RadioGroup gender_rad,user_type_rad;
private RadioButton gender_rb,user_rb;
private String first_name,last_name,email_id,mobile_no,password,address,gender,user_type;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    getDetails();
    setDetails();
    if(validation())
    {
        onClickRegister_driver();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "please fill all the details!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void onClickRegister_driver()
{
    register_user = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register_btn);
    register_user.setOnClickListener(

            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.cablocator.my.cablocator.SetupDriver");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );

}




public void getDetails()
{
    first_name_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstname_txt);
    last_name_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastname_txt);
    email_id_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_txt);
    mobile_no_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile_txt);
    password_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_txt);
    address_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address_txt);
    gender_rad = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender_radio);
    user_type_rad = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.user_type_radio);
    int selected_gender = gender_rad.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    gender_rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected_gender);
    int selected_user_type = user_type_rad.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    user_rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected_user_type);
}

public void setDetails()
{
    first_name = first_name_et.getText().toString().trim();
    last_name = last_name_et.getText().toString().trim();
    email_id = email_id_et.getText().toString().trim();
    mobile_no = mobile_no_et.getText().toString().trim();
    password = password_et.getText().toString().trim();
    address = address_et.getText().toString().trim();
    gender = gender_rb.getText().toString().trim();
    user_type = user_rb.getText().toString().trim();
}

public Boolean validation()
{


    if(first_name.isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(last_name.isEmpty())
    {

        return false;
    }
    else if(email_id.isEmpty())
    {
      return false;
    }
    else if(mobile_no.isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(password.isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(address.isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(gender.isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(user_type.isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
}
```

logcat:

```
10-07 15:40:14.071 4303-4303/com.cablocator.my.cablocator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.cablocator.my.cablocator, PID: 4303
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cablocator.my.cablocator/com.cablocator.my.cablocator.Register}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2576)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.cablocator.my.cablocator.Register.setDetails(Register.java:93)
                                                                            at com.cablocator.my.cablocator.Register.onCreate(Register.java:26)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2576) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me this is showing `NullPointer Exception` when the user dont select and gender in the `radioGroup` If User dnt select and radio Button this leads to `int selected_gender = gender_rad.getCheckedRadioButtonId();` equals to null 
so to ignore this situation put a default gender in radio Group i.e put something in `int selected_gender` by default

Comment: thanks , it worked but now when i click on register button after filling all the details is doesn't do anything and also toast is displayed as soon as activity is loaded can you help please??

Comment: it may be because the intent you are calling is not being executes check the logcat and put it on debug to see the flow of the code... voteUp if u agree with this answer Thank You @user3489970

Comment: please change your code and call the validation method on the click of "register_user" not in if condition apple the validation method in on click and toast in it too

Comment: still the same but now the toast is not displayed on the start of activity since i put it in click of register_user. u can suggest an alternate approach also :-)